# What semantic notions underlie 吳 (shouting) with 夨 (man with tilted head)?

Tags: glyph-origin

Reading [誤's etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%AA%A4#Chinese) spurred me to read [吳's etymology](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%B3#Chinese). Shouting doesn't require you to tilt your head, so why was 夨  used? Why not just use 人?

> ### Glyph origin
>
> Ideogrammic compound (*[會意](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%83%E6%84%8F#Chinese)*): *[口](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%A3#Chinese)* (“mouth”) + *[夨](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%A4%A8#Chinese)* (“man with tilted head”) – to speak loudly.
>
> ### Definitions
>
> 1. † to [speak](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/speak) [loudly](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/loudly); to [shout](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shout)
> 2. † [big](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/big)
> 3. ([historical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#historical)) ([～國](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%B3%E5%9C%8B#Chinese)) one of the [Warring States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)
> 4. ([historical](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary#historical)) ([～國](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%B3%E5%9C%8B#Chinese)) [Eastern Wu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Wu), one of the [Three Kingdoms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Three_Kingdoms)
> 5. the territory those states held, around the [Yangtze](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Yangtze) delta
> 6. [Wu](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wu); the Chinese dialects of that territory, including [Suzhounese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Suzhounese) and [Shanghainese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Shanghainese)
>
>    ⇒ [吳語](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%90%B3%E8%AA%9E#Chinese)
> 7. A [surname](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/surname)​.
>
>    **吳**[作](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%9C#Chinese)[棟](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%A3%9F#Chinese) / **吴**[作](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%BD%9C#Chinese)[栋](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%A0%8B#Chinese) [[Min Nan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min_Nan)]  ―  ***Gô͘** Chok-tòng* [[Pe̍h-ōe-jī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pe%CC%8Dh-%C5%8De-j%C4%AB)]  ―  [**Goh** Chok Tong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goh_Chok_Tong) (Singapore's second Prime Minister; currently Emeritus Senior Minister)
> 8. (～[港](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%B8%AF#Chinese)) a harbor in [Hiroshima](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hiroshima) Prefecture, Japan

Answer (score 1):

This question is actually a good example of why Ancient Chinese scribes cannot keep on drawing pictures to represent words. They can avoid similar-looking or similar-meaning character components to a degree to distinguish between different words, but at some stage, it will become easier to incorporate a component which refers to the sound of a word rather purely relying on the meaning of a word.

[*Person* (人) + *mouth* (口) has already been used for the character 「兄」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=177).

<kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
[甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
[image]
[甲](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)2292
[合集20014](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=20014&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>今
[楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
[image]</kbd>

*Front view of a person* (大, no tilted head) + *mouth* (口) has already been used for the following character:

<kbd>商
甲
[image]
後2.18.7
[合集3028](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=3028&jgwfl=)</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
[image]</kbd>